# how to compare if two values are the same but different cases in python

Tags: python

So the exercise I'm doing goes:

> 086 Ask the user to enter a new password. Ask them to enter it again.
> If the two passwords match, display “Thank you”. If the letters
> are correct but in the wrong case, display th emessage “They must be in
> the same case”,otherwise display the message “Incorrect”.

My attempt looks like this:

```
passw = input("Enter password: ")
passw2 = input("Enter password again: ")
if passw == passw2:
    print("Thank you.")
elif passw != passw2 and passw.lower == passw2.lower:
    print("They must be in the same case.")
else: 
    print("Incorrect.")
```

That didn't give me the result I was hoping for though.
This should be really simple but as you can tell I'm a beginner :)
Thank you in Advance!

*Marcel*

Comment: One minor change, if passw == passw2 fails in first if case, do we still need to check passw != passw2 in other elif case.

Comment: @ChiragPatel we dont need to check that again …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `elif` condition always evaluates to `True`:

```py
elif passw != passw2 and passw.lower == passw2.lower:
```

`str.lower` is a function, and comparing a function with the same function logically ends up being `True`. You have to call the functions instead and compare their results. Additionally, you are doing comparing `passw` and `passw` twice : once you check if they are the same in the `if` condition, and once you check if they are not the same in the `elif` condition. This is useless, because the `elif` condition will only ever be executed when the `if` condition was `False`. Following the working code:

```py
passw = input("Enter password: ")
passw2 = input("Enter password again: ")
if passw == passw2:
    print("Thank you.")
elif passw.lower() == passw2.lower():
    print("They must be in the same case.")
else: 
    print("Incorrect.")
```

Answer (score 3):

That `passw.lower` **is** a method, the method itself, you may call it to have the password in lowercase. Also remove `passw != passw2` in second `ìf` that's mandatory `True`

```
if passw == passw2:
    print("Thank you.")
elif passw.lower() == passw2.lower():
    print("They must be in the same case.")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
```

More

```
passw = "Abc"

print(passw.lower(), "/", type(passw.lower()))
# abc / <class 'str'>

print(passw.lower, "/", type(passw.lower))
# <built-in method lower of str object at 0x00000202611D4730> / <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```